# Change Order Of List of Objects With Another List

Tags: python

This is similar to the other postings that try to reorder a list from another list but this is trying to do it from an attribute from a list of objects. `list_a` has numbers 1-5 and the test_list object list contains attributes of also 1-5. I want to rearrange those list attributes to the order that is found in `list_a`. Here is my code, please help:

```
class tests():
    def __init__(self,grade):
        self.grade = grade


test_list = []

for x in range(1,6):
    test_object = tests(x)
    test_list.append(test_object)

for x  in test_list:
    print(x.grade)

list_a = [5,3,2,1,4]

for x in [test_list]:
    test_list.append(sorted(x.grade,key=list_a.index))
print(test_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a suitable key and use a dictionary as key-function:

> ```
> class tests():
>     def __init__(self,grade):
>         self.grade = grade
>
> test_list = []
>
> for x in range(1,6):
>     test_object = tests(x)
>     test_list.append(test_object)
>
> for x  in test_list:
>     print(x.grade, end = "  ")  # modified
>
> print("")
>
> list_a = [5,3,2,1,4]
> ```

```
# works because unique values, if you had dupes, only the last occurence would 
# be used for sorting
d_a = { val:pos for pos,val in enumerate(list_a,1)}

test_list.sort(key = lambda x: d_a[x.grade]) 

for x  in test_list:
    print(x.grade, end = "  ")
```

Output:

```
# before
1  2  3  4  5  

# after
5  3  2  1  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to order based on a dictionary lookup:

```
test_cache = {}

for test in test_list:
    test_cache[test.grade] = test # store the object based on the test score

sorted_objects = []
for x in list_a:
    sorted_objects.append(test_cache.get(x)) # build the output list based on the score

print [test.grade for test in sorted_objects]
```

output:

```
[5, 3, 2, 1, 4]
```